# Change Action of a button depending on a Pickerview Choice iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, sdk, action

I explain you what I'm trying to do.

I have a PickerView, and a button, i'd like when I select the row "Action1" on my Pickerview, the action become a UIAlert when i click on my button., and when I select the row 'Action2', the action become a ModalTransition when i click on my button.

How I can do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a method for button click as

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in method you can implement a case where the case options can be the values from the picker output(set a integer to know the selected index of picker via `UIPickerViewDelegates` (`pickeroption`)

```
-(void)method1
{
switch pickeroption
case 1:
Action1
break;
case2: 
action 2
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple solution to do this

1. Set Button Tag as per PickerView selection and in Action/Selector Method you can create Switch Case based on Tag. And can perform Action
2. You can directly make switch case on Picker View in Action/ Selector Method.

But if you want to set Multiple selector on different state of button you can use

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(method2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Hope this will help you out.